# Issues with the Image datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Can you please take a moment to answer the below questions about SQL Server

1. What kind of images files (ex. jpg) can the datatype `image` can handle?
2. My images in the columns are of big size and I wanted to load to other tables in SQL Server, but it is taking time to load because of the huge image file size. The datatype is `image`. Do we have an alternative way to load the files more quickly?

We cannot change the datatype to `VarBinary` as well as the DB is designed that way

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server are you running? The `image` datatype is/being deprecated so won't be there in future versions.

To answer your question though, it's a variable-length binary column, so you can store any image format you like, as long as what you are returning it to understands what it is then you should be ok:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/ms187993.aspx

I understand your hands may be tied, and depending on your application, I would recommend not storing images in the database. If you can try instead storing a path to an image, and have the image itself sitting on a file or web server somewhere. This will free up resources on your database server for database things.